# Laravel Eloquent ORM "whereHas" through table

Tags: sql, laravel, orm, eloquent

Hey I have a problem with Laravel on my site [Phones number lookup](http://phoneslookup.com/). I try to choose places that have city that I choose, through contact table.

My model classes:
Places class:

```
class Places extends Eloquent {
    public function contacts()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Contacts');
    }
     public function clubs()
     {
        return $this->hasOne('Clubs');
     }    
}
```

Contacts class:

```
 class Contacts extends Eloquent {
     public function cities()
     {
         return $this->hasOne('Cities');
     }
   }
```

Cities class:

```
 class Cities extends Eloquent {

 }
```

My query:

```
$view->clubs = Places::whereHas('contacts',function ($q) use($city_id){
           $q->where('contacts', function ($q) use($city_id){
               $q->where('id', $city_id);
            });
        })->get();
```

Error msg:

> MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where `id` = ?)) >= 1' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `places` where (select count(*) from `contacts` where `contacts`.`places_id` = `places`.`id` and `contacts` = (select * where `id` = 2223)) >= 1)

I know it is missing "from" `citites` but I do not know how to achieve it.
[image: Model relationships]

Comment: A Place only has one contact and a contact only has one city therefore a place will only have one city is that correct?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have 3 options using relations:

1 most straightforward solution:

```
Places::whereHas('contacts',function ($q) use ($city_id){
       $q->whereHas('cities', function ($q) use ($city_id){
           $q->where('id', $city_id);
        });
    })->get();
```

2 the same as above but using this PR: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/4954

```
Places::whereHas('contacts.cities', function ($q) use ($city_id){
        $q->where('id', $city_id);   
    })->get();
```

3 Using `hasManyThrough` relation:

```
// Place model
public function cities()
{
  return $this->hasManyThrough('City', 'Contact');
}

// then
Places::whereHas('cities',function ($q) use ($city_id){
   $q->where('cities.id', $city_id);
})->get();
```

---

### edit

Having your schema it's obvious that none of the suggest or your original setup can work.

This is a many-to-many relation which in Eloquent is `belongsToMany`:

```
// Places model
public function cities()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('Cities', 'contacts', 'places_id', 'cities_id')
    ->withPivot( .. contacts table fields that you need go here.. );
}

// Cities model
public function places()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('Places', 'contacts', 'cities_id', 'places_id')
    ->withPivot( .. contacts table fields that you need go here.. );
}
```

Then you can call relations like this:

```
$city = Cities::first();
$city->places; // collection of Places models

// contacts data for a single city-place pair
$city->places->first()->pivot->open_hours; // or whatever you include in withPivot above
```

Now, there's another way to setup this, in case you need also `Contacts` model itself:

```
// Places model
public function contact()
{
  return $this->hasOne('Contacts', 'places_id');
}

// Contacts model
public function city()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('Cities', 'cities_id');
}

public function place()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('Places', 'places_id');
}

// Cities model
public function contact()
{
  return $this->hasOne('Contacts', 'cities_id');
}
```

then:

```
$city = Cities::first();
$city->contact; // Contacts model
$city->contact->place; // Places model
```

`hasManyThrough` won't work here at all

Comment: I tried to do it at the beginning like option 2 but I get this error: Call to undefined method Illuminate \ Database \ Query \ Builder :: contacts.cities () Despite the fact that I have in the class contacts function: public function cities (). Why?

Comment: @PiotrSuchanek like I wrote this can be achieved with the PR that I linked. Currently it is not supported in the `Eloquent`. You can use 1st instead for the time being, or pull that PR of mine.

Comment: Hi, I tried both methods and I get a similar error:  Unknown column 'cities.contacts_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select * from `places` where (select count(*) from `cities` inner join `contacts` on `contacts`.`id` = `cities`.`contacts_id` where `places`.`id` = `contacts`.`places_id` and `cities`.`id` = 2223) >= 1).
Table Cities doesn't have have column contacts_id. Places table has it. Any solution?

Comment: What's the foreign key name? You have plural model name which isn't what Eloquent expects. That's why it tries to guess the key (since you didn't specify it on the relation) and looks for `contacts_id`, while I suppose it is `contact_id`

Comment: I added this: return $this->hasManyThrough('Cities', 'Contacts', 'cities_id','contacts_id'); and still and still get the same error. I also added the picture in my question, which can help.

Comment: Man, you have m-m relationship there! This is `belongsToMany` or `hasOne`+`belongsTo` if you need pivot model. Check the edit in a moment

Comment: thank man
you area life saver. Keep up the good work

Answer (score 0):

As you know the city id and from this you want to find the corresponding place you can start at the city and work back to the place. To do this you will need to define the inverse of your relationships.

```
// Add this function to your Cities Model
public function contact()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Contact');
}


// Add this function to your Contacts Model
public function place()
{
     return $this->belongsTo('Places');
}
```

Now you can query the City and find Place.

```
$place = Cities::find($city_id)->contact->place;
```

**EDIT:**
Added missing return in functions

Comment: I try this and got this error: Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation

Comment: This will also work in your case, however there are `return` missing in the @RMcLeod examples. Just add `return` statement to both methods and it will work

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT * from pemeriksaan_ginekologi_iva where id in
(
SELECT m1.id
FROM pemeriksaan_ginekologi_iva m1 LEFT JOIN pemeriksaan_ginekologi_iva m2
 ON (m1.id_klien = m2.id_klien AND m1.id < m2.id)
WHERE m2.id IS NULL
) and id_klien in (select id from klien where id_kelurahan =1)
AND (hasil_periksa='IVA Negatif / Normal')  traslate to laravel
```

Comment: This answer would be greatly improved if you could explain how this solves the problem :)